# Migrating from SQLite to Android Room Persistence Library

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-room

I have an app which is using `SQLite` database and I am trying to replace Android `SQLite` with `Android Room API.` I have created DAO class, Entity class, and DB but while executing database query in `Async` task I am getting following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 3 to 1
>   is necessary. Please provide a Migration in the builder or call
>   fallbackToDestructiveMigration in the builder in which case Room will
>   re-create all of the tables.
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:82)
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onDowngrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:94)
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onDowngrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:128)
>                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:254)
>                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:93)
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
>                                                                     at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:193)
>                                                                     at com.rasfi.ai.domain.room.RecordingDAO_Impl.getAll(RecordingDAO_Impl.java:112)
>                                                                     at com.rasfi.ai.ui.acivities.HomeActivity$1.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:106)
>                                                                     at com.rasfi.ai.ui.acivities.HomeActivity$1.doInBackground(HomeActivity.java:102)
>                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)  01-10 08:13:37.648
>   30267-30339/com.rasfi.ai E/UncaughtException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                        at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)

I am unable to understand what I am missing, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to move from SQLite db version 3 to Room db version 1. Sure the ROOM uses the same db and versioning(it is only abstraction layer over SQLite), your room doesn't know how to manage going from version 3 to 1.

You should increase version in Room to 4 and specify empty migration:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_3_4 = new Migration(3, 4) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
// Since we didn't alter the table, there's nothing else to do here.
    }
};
```

add it to room :

```
database = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
        UsersDatabase.class, "Sample.db")
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_3_4)
        .build();
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks for this.