# Runtime exception from room in a project that is not using room

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I suddnly started getting this runtime exception at app launch without having room as my dependency at all.

```
07-20 19:48:37.703 18737-18771/mypackage.x E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
    Process: mypackage, PID: 18737
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 3 to 2 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:97)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onDowngrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:109)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onDowngrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:144)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:396)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
        at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.compileStatement(RoomDatabase.java:244)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.createNewStatement(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:65)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.getStmt(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:72)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire(SharedSQLiteStatement.java:87)
        at androidx.work.impl.model.WorkSpecDao_Impl.resetScheduledState(WorkSpecDao_Impl.java:337)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.rescheduleEligibleWork(WorkManagerImpl.java:514)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

here are some of the dependencies that I do have from Android arch:

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$ktx_version"
implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:$paging_runtime"
implementation("android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$android_arc_version") {
    force = true
}

implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigation_version"
// use -ktx for Kotlin
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigation_version"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"
```

Any idea what might have caused this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `android.arch.work:work` had a dependency to the room library and I was using the version `1.0.0-alpha03` of work library. I thought of excluding the dependency but I noticed that an update is available for the work component and after trying that, it fixed the issue. So upgrade your work library to fix the issue (at this time the updated version is `1.0.0-alpha04`)

Comment: Your answer is intended to earn more rate. I came here from an exception by Room, and migration has nothing with a version of the library.

Comment: @CoolMind In the title of the question I have mentioned "in a project that is not using room" so you are in the wrong place if you are using room.

Comment: Yes, agree. Strange that this exception appeared in an application without Room. By the way, I wrote migration scripts and solved a problem.

Comment: @CoolMind I'm facing similar issue like yours. Room database migration test is throwing this error. Can you please guide me on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shakunthalaMK, where have you stopped? Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769772/java-lang-illegalstateexception-migration-didnt-properly-handle-table, https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929. If you wish, i can add an answer here.

Comment: @CoolMind I have got the following error. I am actually doing Room database migration unit testing. jError: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 13 to 11 was required but not found. Please provide the necessary Migration path via RoomDatabase.Builder.addMigration(Migration ...) or allow for destructive migrations via one of the RoomDatabase.Builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration* methods.

Comment: @shakunthalaMK, does it mean, that Room worked right, migrations have executed from 1 to 13 DB versions, but after starting tests they failed? Didn't you downgrade the app? I wrote migrations: in `AppDatabase` added `val migrations = DbMigrations(context)`, `instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME).addMigrations(migrations.migration_1_2).build()`, also in `migrations.xml` wrote scripts. I upgraded from 1 to 2.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179598/migrating-from-sqlite-to-android-room-persistence-library?rq=1. Maybe you replaced a DB. Or for experiment write a migration from 13 to 11. Or your apk contains a DB 13, but in a test you try to upgrade from 10 to 11 (I don't know where it is possible).

Comment: @CoolMind Will check it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @shakunthalaMK, welcome. Will be glad to hear you again.